# hide/delete "Create Account" link from Meteor signup utility

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

How to hide or permanently remove "Create Account" link from Meteor Accounts utility?

Html code for it is as below;

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
    <input id="login-username" type="text" placeholder="Username" class="form-control">
    <input id="login-password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">

    <button class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12 col-sm-12" id="login-buttons-password" type="button">
        Sign in
    </button>

    <div id="login-other-options">
    <a id="signup-link" class="pull-right">Create account</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I used code `$("#login-other-options").remove();` it works on Chrome but not on Firefox. So any universal technique?

I have below package installed.

```
ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3
accounts-password@1.3.6
```

below is the image.

[image]

Comment: Does `$("#signup-link").remove();` work?

Comment: @charlesreid1 : Not on Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide "Create Account" button you can use (on server):

```
Accounts.config({forbidClientAccountCreation: true});
```

Though, this will forbid it only on client side, as explained [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/a549448e54582d49941f50225121015bf3b31e81/packages/accounts-base/accounts_common.js#L68-L72).

[Documentation on `AccountsCommon.config`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsCommon-config).

**Added**:

Another option will be just hide it using CSS:

```css
#login-other-options { display: none !important; }
```

Comment: Error: Accounts.ui.config: Invalid key: forbidClientAccountCreation

Comment: @AnkurSoni Sorry, fixed my answer. There should be `AccountsCommon` instead.

Comment: I guess i do not have that package. it says `Uncaught ReferenceError: AccountsCommon is not defined`

Comment: @AnkurSoni Well then, you should specify what you _do_ have :) And also, what "Meteor Accounts utility" means in your question.

Comment: updated question with package description. Sorry I missed that.

Comment: @AnkurSoni I'm sorry again, I've got you (and myself) confused. You should use `Accounts.config` on server, not on client.

Comment: @AnkurSoni Just to be sure, you do **not** call `Accounts.ui.config` instead of `Accounts.config`, right?